# Connection to work or school already used by another user on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, user-accounts

Error: "Another user on the System is already connected to a work or School. Please remove that work or School Connection and try again."

I removed the user, but that didn't help.
It was a local user.
How can I now remove this Connection without the user left?

[image: screenshot of error]

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser, make sure any other user on your system isn't connected to the work or school. Are you connected from any other computer with same credentials?

Comment: yes I was connected from another computer with the same credentials.
As it was a test system I basically reimaged it, from there on it worked again. Sorry I can't provide a more useful update.#

Answer (score 1):

This error occurred while you try to enrol your device and device is already enrolled with someone else. You can overcome this issue by deleting the registry key.

Open `Regedit` as an administrator and follow the path `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Enrollments` then expand it and go through with all subkeys and look for the **subkeys**.

Look for the username on the right side panel, so you can make sure it is a relevant key. Now delete the subkey where username is showing and try to enrol it once again, it might help you.